# What does $\Delta_p$ denote in $p$-Laplace equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

What does $\Delta_p$ denote in $p$-Laplace equation?

Why isn't it $\Delta_{p-2}$?

The $p$-Laplace equation is:

$$- \Delta_p u = - \text{div} ( | \nabla u |^{p-2} \nabla u) = 0$$

Comment: I'm guessing it denotes the operator $\text{div} ( | \nabla \cdot |^{p-2} \nabla \cdot)$, in other words, the first equality expresses a definition, while the second equality is a condition

Comment: @user2520938 Yes, but why isn't it $\triangle_{p-2}$ then?

Comment: Well apparently whoever introduced this notation felt the shift in $p$ made sense. Its not uncommon that the symbol for some operator is indexed by $p$, but the operator only uses shifts of $p$.

Answer (score 1):

The operator $\triangle_p$ is related to $L^p$-space instead of $L^{p-2}$ space.
 For instance, $\triangle_p$ is a maximal monotone operator from $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ into $(W_0^{1,p}(\Omega))'$. If $p=2$,  $\triangle_p$ is a "natural" operator in $L^2$ space.

Comment: I'm not familiar with $L^p$ spaces, but how's it seen from the $p$-Laplacian?

Answer (score 1):

The $p$-Laplace equation is the [Euler–Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) for the $p$-energy
$$
E_p[u] = \int |\nabla u|^p
$$
That is, a function that minimizes $E_p$ subject to some boundary conditions is a solution of the $p$-Laplace equation. So it makes sense that $p$ is the number associated to it. It's also the exponent of the natural domain of definition of $\Delta_p$, which is the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}$. Indeed, being in this space is what one needs to have $E_p$ finite.